# SharePoint 2010: Register InfoPath forms and use custom feature receiver jointly

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, infopath

I am using Custom InfoPath Task Forms in my project. For form registering, I am using next code in Feature.Template.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<Feature xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/"
     Title="Prepare workflows"       
     ReceiverClass="Microsoft.Office.Workflow.Feature.WorkflowFeatureReceiver"
     ReceiverAssembly="Microsoft.Office.Workflow.Feature, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c">
   <Properties>
       <Property Key="GloballyAvailable" Value="true" />
       <Property Key="RegisterForms" Value="Forms\*.xsn"/>
   </Properties>
 </Feature>
```

Also I want to use my custom FeatureReceiver (for workflow associating). But I don't know, how can I use it both (it works perfectly separately). Is any way to do it (may be, call to registration method of Microsoft.Office.Workflow.Feature.WorkflowFeatureReceiver in FeatureInstalled in my receiver?

I can try to do registration of my forms whole from the code in my feature receiver, but I think, may be there is a different, more elegant approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the Kai, solution was found. You have to inherit your receiver not from SPFeatureReceiver, and from Microsoft.Office.Workflow.Feature.WorkflowFeatureReceiver using calls to base.FeatureActivated(properties) if it needs.